# Удалить запятые из массива JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть массив. Он отображает название и цену товара и кнопку, а после кнопки запятая, как убрать запятую?

```js
const products = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Notebook',
    price: 1000
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Mouse',
    price: 100
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Keyboard',
    price: 250
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Gamepad',
    price: 150
  },
];

const renderProduct = (title, price) => {
  return `<div class="product-item">
                <h3>${title}</h3>
                <p>${price}</p>
                <button class="by-btn">Добавить</button>
              </div>`;
};

const renderProducts = list => {
  const productList = list.map(item => renderProduct(item.title, item.price));
  document.querySelector('.products').innerHTML = productList;
};

renderProducts(products);
```

```html
<div class="products"></div>
```

Comment: Не надо так данные в разметку подставлять.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При присваивании массива свойству [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), у него автоматически вызывается метод [`.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString), который эквивалентен вызову метода [`.join(',')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Таким образом, если разделители не нужны, необходимо вызвать `.join` явно, передав ему в качества параметра пустую строку:

```
.innerHTML = productList.join('')
```

Comment: Да! Супер, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Так как Вы используете `innerHTML` которое ожидает в качестве объекта приваивания строку, будет логичнее использовать функцию массива `reduce` которая может использоваться для массива в любой легальный объект, в данном случае в строку:

```js
const products = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Notebook',
    price: 1000
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Mouse',
    price: 100
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Keyboard',
    price: 250
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Gamepad',
    price: 150
  },
];

const renderProduct = (title, price) => {
  return `<div class="product-item">
                <h3>${title}</h3>
                <p>${price}</p>
                <button class="by-btn">Добавить</button>
              </div>`;
};

const renderProducts = list => {
  const productList = list.reduce((acc, item) => acc + renderProduct(item.title, item.price), '');
  document.querySelector('.products').innerHTML = productList;
};

renderProducts(products);
```

```html
<div class="products"></div>
```